# Twig loader crushes with October CMS

Tags: php, twig, octobercms

When I start fresh october project it says:

> Class System\Twig\Loader contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Twig_LoaderInterface::getSourceContext) /home/doctor/web/paintshop/modules/system/twig/Loader.php line 82

[image]

Did anyone faced such problem? My php version is 7, and php7 mod is enabled in apache, while php 5.6 mod is disabled. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of cases if you have a fresh OctoberCMS install it won't be the latest update.

Go to `Config/Cms.php` and set `edgeUpdates` to `true` and try to update the application from backend.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your reply! I thought I were using the latest version because of "october:update" executed, but backend update fixed the problem.

Comment: I'm glad it's fixed. Don't forget to mark my answer as the right one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have problems, you can try to switch to pulling from the dev branch instead by setting the require property of your `composer.json` to the dev branch for the library and then running `composer update`

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "october/rain": "dev-develop",
    "october/system": "dev-develop",
    "october/backend": "dev-develop",
    "october/cms": "dev-develop",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "dev-master",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2"
},
```

The reason for the problem is that the Twig dependency in the OctoberCMS Library `composer.json` was recently updated to include `v2.0` which the library doesn't officially support yet as Twig v2 doesn't support below PHP 7 while October does still. The reversion back to just Twig v1.30 was just made a couple of hours ago, hence why you might need to update from the dev branch of the library to pull your changes.